# OnTriggerEnter can't detect my Transform tag

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm making a simple zombie survival game. I've a problem with this code, which detects only one trigger, but not the other.

```
#pragma strict

var health = 100;
var attack = 10;
var delay = 5;
var scream : AudioClip;
var player : Collider;

function OnTriggerEnter () {

    if (player.gameObject.tag == "ZombieFlame") {
        gameObject.Find("Flame").SendMessage("OnTriggerEnter");
    }

    if (player.gameObject.tag == "Zombie") {
        Attack ();
    }

    if (health == 0) {
        Debug.Log("Die!");
        Lose ();
        }
    }

function Attack () {
    health -= attack;
    Debug.Log("Under attack!");
    audio.PlayOneShot(scream);
    yield WaitForSeconds(delay);
    Loop ();
}

function Loop () {
    OnTriggerEnter ();
}

function Lose () {
    this.active = false;
}
```

My script detects the "ZombieFlame" but not the "Zombie". The gameObjects already have the tag, so I don't know what is going on. It's checked like Trigger, too.

Comment: "that Transform have already the tag" — I don't understand what this means.

Comment: What's exactly the configuration of all the GameObjects you use?

Comment: My inglish bad... I tried to say "the transform already have the tag"

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing any parameter in the function function OnTriggerEnter (). It should have a collider parameter. Use like this-

```
 function OnTriggerEnter (other : Collider) {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "ZombieFlame") {
        gameObject.Find("Flame").SendMessage("OnTriggerEnter");
//It may give error for the Flame's OnTriggerEnter() function without
//parameter. I don't really get why are you sending message to Flame.
//You can remove this if the Flame has script attached containing
//OnTriggerEnter(other : Collider). And check if 'other' is this player or 
//other gameobject collider as this function. It will give you more control.
    }

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Zombie") {
        Attack ();
    }

    if (health == 0) 
        Debug.Log("Die!");
        Lose ();
    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried with that... I receive an error:

The best overload from the method Health.OnTriggerEnter(UnityEngine.Collider) is not compatible with the argument list '()'.

Comment: How is the Health class look like? In which line you got the error? I think you have to change lot of stuff here and there to work on.

Comment: You right... the problem is the function Loop.
I'm gonna to create a boolean state "isAttacked"... I don't know much of this, but thanks for your help. Greetings.